# Checking default values of properties

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox, user-input

If you have used asp.net you will see that when validating a model you can just do

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

And then you can validate the model automatically. I'm trying to build the model validation in windows forms.
I have this to validate my model and it's working but there's a problem. When I enter  a text in the textbox and I delete it,the value becomes empty so the value is no longer null. How can I check for default values in this manner as I'm using reflection

```
private void ValidateModel(TModel _model)
{
   foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in _model.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
      if (propInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(RequiredAttribute)) != null && propInfo.GetValue(_model) == null)
      {
       
        if(propInfo.GetValue(_model) == default)
        {
           InvalidProperty = propInfo.Name;
           Errors.Add($"The {propInfo.Name} field is required")
           IsValid = false;
           continue;
        }
       
      }
   }
}
```

Consider this example, a user passed an object which is to be stored to the database and you have to write a generic method to validate it no matter the type or where the input was gotten

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get;  set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get;  set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string DOB { get;  set; }
    //......Other properries
}
```

and then you have to do something like

```
var state = new ModelState(user);
if (state.IsValid)
{
    //Use error provider to show appropriate errors
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [the ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/errorprovider-component-overview-windows-forms)?

Comment: Yes. The error provider is actually for displaying errors not validating them according to that documentation. I have to validate the error before showing the error message. Take a look at my update

Comment: It has an [api for validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.geterror?view=netcore-3.1) but I don't want to dissuade you from rolling your own.

Comment: @Crowcoder that example does not check for required fields on a model or something like if model is an email. What it does is try use the values of the textbox if it throws an error then the input is invalid.

Comment: Yes, in winforms it is common to only care about data bound to controls but if that doesn't suit your needs or is not appropriate then forget I mentioned it. There is also an [IValidatableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject?view=netcore-3.1) interface that you can implement if you are interested in following a known convention.